# Specific descriptors for dimers

Tags: machine-learning, cheminformatics

I am studying the dependence of the rate of a specific process in a dimer from the relative positioning of molecules in the dimer. Currently, I am using 2000 descriptors from the padelpy for model training. In addition, I am using 8 different distances between atoms of the molecules in the dimer as descriptors. However, I have noticed that my ML model gives poor predictions, and I suspect that it may be due to insufficient information about the positioning of molecules in the dimer used for training.

What descriptors can be used to describe the relative positioning of molecules in a dimer with respect to each other?

Comment: It is currently not clear as to what property are you trying to target. If the property that you are interested only depends on the relative positions of the two molecules, you can use the distance between the centre of masses and define an orientation vector that would say how one molecule is oriented wrt to another